# Why is the page count incorrect in a generated PDF?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, pdfbox

Using spring framework library(pdf-box) and thymleaf, I'm generating PDF, in HTML I've specified page count as

```
@page {
  size: A4 landscape;
   @bottom-right {
    content: counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
   }
}
```

this gives the wrong total page count, I'm getting 27 total page count for 17 pages.
how to fix this HTML counter issue in the landscape mode of the page.

Comment: PDFBox is a java tool. Please rework your question so that it focuses on Java only and mention the version you're using (should be 2.0.24) and share the PDF.

Comment: Yes share your resulting PDF file then we are able to help you. Welcome to SO...